# Como faço para criar um modelo de String e sempre que o usuário passar algo diferente reporte o erro?

Tags: java, regex

Preciso de um modelo de String que comece com letra, não tenho espaço, aceite números, é case sensitive, (maiúsculas e minusculas) e não aceite caracteres especiais nem acentos, (vai ser o nome de uma tabela no banco de dados) então queria algo que funcionasse como filtro para aceitar ou não. Qual é o melhor jeito de fazer isso? O ideal era apontar o que ta fora, mas não precisa necessariamente.

Hoje faço algo assim:

```
    String escreve = (escrevetabela.getText().toString()).replaceAll(" ","");

                if(escreve.indexOf("0")==0||escreve.indexOf("1")==0||
                        escreve.indexOf("2")==0||escreve.indexOf("3")==0||
                        escreve.indexOf("4")==0||escreve.indexOf("5")==0||
                        escreve.indexOf("6")==0||escreve.indexOf("7")==0||
                        escreve.indexOf("8")==0||escreve.indexOf("9")==0||
                        escreve.indexOf("9")==0){

mas como descobri que caracteres especial da problema também, essa lista de ous ia ficar um tanto extensa.
```

***Utilizando a resposta abaixo com algumas modificações ficou assim:***

```
    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String escreve = (escrevetabela.getText().toString()).replaceAll(" ","");
                Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]\\w+");

                Matcher m = p.matcher(escreve);
                if(m.find() && m.group().length() == escreve.length()) {
                    insert       (escreve);
                    abrebanco2   (escreve);
                    iniciartabela(escreve);
                    fechabanco();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(adcionartabela.this,gerenciar2.class);
                    intent.putExtra("pagina", page2);
                    intent.putExtra("tabbanco", tabbancos);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    adcionartabela.this.finish();
                }
                else {
                    AlertDialog.Builder mensagem = 
                            new AlertDialog.Builder(adcionartabela.this);
                    mensagem.setTitle("Atenção!");
                    mensagem.setMessage("Nome inválido, não inicie com caracter numérico, use somente letras e números, não utilize espaços.");
                    mensagem.setNeutralButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                        }});
                    mensagem.show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Vlw Math

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acredito que a maneira mais fácil de fazer isso é usando Regex.

Para o seu caso, utilize o padrão `"^[a-zA-Z]\\w+"`.

Um exemplo de código que utiliza o Regex acima:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Regex {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] palavras = new String[]{"teste1", "teste 2", "3o.teste", "téste4"};
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]\\w+");
        for(String s: palavras) {
            Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
            if(m.find() && m.group().length() == s.length()) {
                System.out.println("padrão ok");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("fugiu do padrão");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Resultado:

> padrão ok
>   fugiu do padrão
>   fugiu do padrão
>   fugiu do padrão